# Why can't we add block around property getter field in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have written code below first example works but the second example throws an error "inferred Unit expecting Int"

***First Example***

```
class Time(time: Int){
   var time: Int = time
     get()= if(field > 127){
            127
          }else if(){
           -128
          }
          else{
            field
          }
}
```

---

Second Example

---

```
class Time(time: Int){
   var time: Int = time
      get()= {
          if(field > 127){
            127
          }else if(){
            -128
          }
          else{
            field
          }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to recognize in your second example is that `get()` is not of type `Int` (as you've declared in the first example) and is instead of type `() -> Int`.

It may be worth reviewing some of the docs on [higher order functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) along with [properties and fields](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) for good measure.

A third correct example equivalent to your first would be: (just in case it's helpful)

```
class Time(time: Int){
   var time: Int = time
      get(): Int {
          return if(field > 127){
            127
          }else if(){
            -128
          }
          else{
            field
          }
        }
}
```